# how to find and push data into array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have used this schema:-

```
var candidateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    partyName: {type: String, unique: true},
    information: String
});
var candidate = mongoose.model("candidate", candidateSchema);

var adminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    electionName : {type: String, unique: true},
    endDate      : {type: Date},
    candidates   : [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
                    ref: "candidate"}]  
});
 var addElection = mongoose.model("addElection", adminSchema);
```

How can i push the candidateSchema's data into candidate[] array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add, use `$push`

```
var candidateItem = new candidate({
    name: 'something'
});
candidateItem.save(function(err) {
    // addElection schema
    addElection.update({id: 123}, {$push: {candidates: candidateItem}}, function(err) {
        // saved
    });
    // addElection schema instance
    addElectionItem.update({$push: {candidates: candidateItem}}, function(err) {
        // saved
    });
});
```

To remove, use `$pull`

```
var candidateId = 567;
addElection.update({id: 123}, {$pull: {candidates: candidateId}});
```